# Recognizing Ctrl+KEY in case in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, input, case, ctrl

I've searched forever for an answer and cannot find one, so now i must ask.

Im working on a script in that creates a textstring as a T9 Numpad (without the dictionary) by cycling through each keys letters.
All of it is working except handling backspace (a real backspace on the numpad). I use "Read -n 1" for the inputs and as far as i have learned backspace maps to "^?" and as far as i know the "^" corresponds to ctrl being pressed while typing "?". I cannot get a case to handle this input, and i dont know what to do. The code works if i substitute backspace for any single key i.e. "-". So i only need to know how i would be able recognize the backspace in read -n and case

Comment: See the output from hitting backspace in this read to see what you get as a result: `read -n 1 bs; printf %q\\n "$bs"`. (Alternatively, `printf %s "$bs" | xxd`.)

Comment: Note that your `stty` settings will affect backspace (^H) and delete (^?) mapping. You may have to do raw input, which can vary the state of your terminal connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$'...'` notation to match a control character in `bash`. `^?` is a C-style notation to represent ASCII 127 (DEL). There are several options:

```
* $'\177' - octal
* $'\x7f' - hexadecimal
```

any of which can be used as a literal pattern to match in the `case` statement.

```
read -n 1 char
case $char in
    $'\177') echo "Backspace" ;;
esac
```